# d3.svg.line() not plotting values

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I wanted to plot a multi-y-axis line graph using d3 version 3.
The data that is being read would be in the following format:

```
{
name: 'sacramento',
violentCrimes: {
        crimes: [183, 168, 147, 158, 195],
        months: ['January 2018', 'February 2018', 'March 2018', 'April 2018', 'May 2018']
    },
nonViolentCrimes: {
        crimes: [1222, 1147, 1162, 1264, 1333],
        months: ['January 2018', 'February 2018', 'March 2018', 'April 2018', 'May 2018']
    }
}
```

I have destructured violent crimes and non violent crimes out of the data and want to plot both on their separate y-axis.
I didn't use d3 parse date method since parsing using new Date() on violentCrimes.months worked just fine for me when I created a simple bar chart just for violent crimes.

The problem that I am encountering is that the var line = d3.svg.line() method is not plotting the data and giving the error Error:  attribute d: Expected number, "MNaN,NaNZ"

I have only mentioned the code for a single y-axis since plotting non-violent crimes on another y-axis would essentially be the same.
Following is my code:

```
var margin = { top: 10, right: 30, bottom: 40, left: 60 },
        width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
        height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var svg = d3.select('body').append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform",
        "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");


d3.json('/sacramento.json', function (error, data) {

    let { violentCrimes, nonViolentCrimes } = data

    //converting string dates to JS date objects
    violentCrimes.months = violentCrimes.months.map(element => {
        return new Date(element);
    });

    //converting into array to be passed into line object
    const violentCrimesArr = [violentCrimes];

    
    var x = d3.time.scale()
        .range([0, width]);
    var y = d3.scale.linear()
        .range([height, 0]);

    var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(x)
        .ticks(violentCrimes.months.length)    
        .tickFormat(d3.time.format("%b %y"))        
        .orient("bottom");
    var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(y)
        .orient("left");
   
    var line = d3.svg.line()
        .x(function (violentCrimesArr) { return x(violentCrimesArr.months); })
        .y(function (d) { return y(violentCrimesArr.crimes); });

   //calculating violent crimes max value for y-axis domain    
    let vcMax = Math.max(...data.violentCrimes.crimes);    

    x.domain([new Date(data.violentCrimes.months[0]), new Date(data.violentCrimes.months[data.violentCrimes.months.length - 1])]);
    y.domain([0, vcMax + 100]); 


    svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "x axis")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
        .call(xAxis)
        .selectAll("text")
        .style("text-anchor", "end")
        .attr("dx", "-.8em")        
        .attr("dy", ".15em")        
        .attr("transform", "rotate(-65)");;

    svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "y axis")
        .call(yAxis)
        .append("text")
        .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
        .attr("y", 6)
        .attr("dy", ".71em")
        .style("text-anchor", "end")
        .text("violent crimes");


    svg.append("path")
        .datum(violentCrimesArr)
        .attr("class", "line")
        .attr("d", line);

});
```

Comment: violentCrimesArr.months are not numbers.

Comment: But x-axis is also a time scale axis. I even tried to create a parse date using
var parseDate = d3.time.format("%B %Y").parse; 
but it still doesn't plot it.
I successfully created a bar graph using a time scale x-axis but I don't know why this doesnt work